# Bootstrap 5 How to add a space between these two cards?

Tags: html

I'm trying to create a space between [two cards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36ZI2.png), but I can't seem to figure it out. This is what I have right now:

```
<div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div class="row d-flex align-items-center" id="recentDiv">
                <div class="col-6 card bg-dark text-white recentPost">
                    <img class="card-img" src="..." alt="Card image">
                    <div class="card-img-overlay">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                      <p class="card-text">Last updated 3 mins ago</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-6 card bg-dark text-white recentPost">
                    <img class="card-img" src="..." alt="Card image">
                    <div class="card-img-overlay">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                      <p class="card-text">Last updated 3 mins ago</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using a CSS grid wihthin Bootstrap. Apply `g-grid gap-3` to the parent `div`. With `gap-{x}` you can decide how big the gaps will be.

On the children instead of `col-6` use `g-col-6`.

> Note: I've used some dummy images to illustrate what it would look like.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center">
  <div class="g-grid gap-3 d-flex align-items-center" id="recentDiv">
    <div class="g-col-6 card bg-dark text-white recentPost">
      <img class="card-img" src="https://dummyimage.com/400x200/000/f0f" alt="Card image">
      <div class="card-img-overlay">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Last updated 3 mins ago</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="g-col-6 card bg-dark text-white recentPost">
      <img class="card-img" src="https://dummyimage.com/400x200/000/f0f" alt="Card image">
      <div class="card-img-overlay">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
        <p class="card-text">Last updated 3 mins ago</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You might need to do some adjustments so it looks good with your images but the general approach should work.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I wasn't aware of the g-grid and gap-3 application here. Though I will definitely look into it :)

Answer (score 0):

The [Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/gutters/) references this.  Basically, add `.gx-{n}` to your `.row` element, where `{n}` is 0-5.  So `gx-1`, `gx-2`, etc.

Comment: Ahh yeah I was trying that out but it didn't seem to work.. However I tried it again just now. Seems like applying the .gx class to the row div was adjusting the gutters inside the .col card, rather than in between the cards themselves. I'm unsure how to make it affect the 2 col-6 cards directly? But I just ended up coloring the background of the card padding to match the background of the section it's in along with the .gx to create the illusion that there's a gap there.

Comment: If you're not concerned with the cards wrapping, another option - which I feel is superior but I can't say why - is to add margins to the cards.  Or, you could add `.gx-{n}` to the cards to reset the gutters.